# ubuntu 16.04 freeze during high cpu activity

Tags: 16.04, freeze, cpu

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to address.

I'm running "heavy" calculations with "Matlab" that use 100% of the cpu, sometimes for days at a time.
Recently, while running, my system started to freeze completely, and I have to do a hard shutdown to restart it. Usually it will work for hours before this happens.

I'm currently running ubuntu 16.04, kernel version: 4.4.0-166-generic.

Additional system info: I have Intel Core i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 12, and 32GB RAM.

I have a very good indication of the time of system freeze because my script writes cache files every few seconds, so I can check after a freeze at what time it occurred. However when I check the various logs at /var/logs, there is no suspicious activity around the freeze time!

Additionally, I know for a fact that the cpus heat up during their run, (up to 90 C), but they have done this also in the past without any problems.

Unfortunately, I don't have "Windows" on my machine, so I can't check if this is a hardware or software issue.

**Update:**

I have cleaned my computer and cpu heat-sink from dust and continued running my calculations. Every now and then the computer freezes seemingly with no culprit. cpu temperatures are also lower now - not exceeding 80C, yet the problem still persists.
I can't find any "suspicious" activity in the system logs near the time the computer freezes. Recently I also had a freeze that occurred while I was working on the computer without running anything, so cpu activity was low!

I have no idea what could be causing this.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: This could just be a case of overheating. As a test, try to make sure the CPU doesn't heat above 80C, by disabling the turbo mode or limiting the highest frequency. Also, make sure the cooler if clean of dust.

Comment: So, I tried running cpufreqd with a rule that limits cpu operation to prevent temperatures higher than 80C. It didn't work. The computer froze again approx. 30 min. after I started running the matlab script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had noticed similar behavior, but not (necessarily) tied to high load. My server ran 4.4.0-164 and after a powerloss booted the then-current 4.4.0-166. Then, after some time it would just freeze. No terminal output during the freeze, no dumps etc. After the third time, i booted with 4.4.0-164 and it is currently running for 10 days without any issue.

Maybe try running an older kernel.

Comment: It seems that indeed the *-166 kernel caused the problem. I didn't have any further issues once I booted with it.